# Net::HTTP -> stack level too deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, https

I get the error 'SystemStackError (stack level too deep)' when I run the following code inside a controller, however it works completely fine inside the ruby terminal!

```
require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'
http = Net::HTTP.new('my.site.com', 443)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE     
resp, data = http.get('/something?info=XX')
```

As far as I can figure out its the last line causing the problem. Hope someone has run into this problem before! I'm on a windows machine, if that's relevant.

Update: the pasted code does work on our fedora server, but it's certainly not fun to develop that way.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this code instead:

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/https'
url = URI("https://foo.bar.com")
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.to_s)
res = Net::HTTP.start(url.hostname, url.port, :use_ssl => true , :verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE) do |http|
    http.request(req)  
end
case res
    when Net::HTTPSuccess, Net::HTTPRedirection
      response = Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query URI.decode(res.body)
      puts response.to_json  
    else
      puts 'OH NO!'
      puts res.to_json
    end
```